# Efficient method to replace values in awkward array according to a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, awkward-array

I have a dictionary with integer keys and float values.
I also have a 2D awkward array with integer entries (I'm using awkward1).
I want to replace these integers with the corresponding float according to the dictionary, keeping the awkward array format.

Assuming the keys run from 0 to 999, my solution so far is something like this:

```
resultArray = ak.where(myArray == 0, myDict.get(0), 0)
for key in range(1,1000):
    resultArray = resultArray + ak.where(myArray == key, myDict.get(key), 0)
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

**Update**

Minimal reproducible example of my working code:

```
import awkward as ak # Awkward 1

myArray = ak.from_iter([[0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]) # Creating example array
myDict = {0: 19.5, 1: 34.1, 2: 10.9}

resultArray = ak.where(myArray == 0, myDict.get(0), 0)
for key in range(1,3):
    resultArray = resultArray + ak.where(myArray == key, myDict.get(key), 0)
```

myArray:

```
<Array [[0, 1], [2, 1, 0]] type='2 * var * int64'>
```

resultArray:

```
<Array [[19.5, 34.1], [10.9, 34.1, 19.5]] type='2 * var * float64'>
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] with appropriate imports, sample input, and desired vs. actual output.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but you might want to consider using `np.searchsorted` as described here: https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/discussions/633 Replace your dict with two NumPy arrays, one with sorted keys and the other with values in the same order. You'll need to flatten/unflatten the Awkward Array, or otherwise extract the one-dimensional arrays from it. An `ak.searchsorted` to do this automatically works be nice, but a convenience function like that does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I mentioned in a comment that [np.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is where you should be looking, I hadn't noticed that `myDict` includes every consecutive integer as a key. Having a dense lookup table like this would allow faster algorithms, which also happen to be simpler in Awkward Array.

So, assuming that there's a key in `myDict` for each integer from `0` up to some value, you can equally well represent the lookup table as

```py
>>> lookup = ak.Array([myDict[i] for i in range(len(myDict))])
>>> lookup
<Array [19.5, 34.1, 10.9] type='3 * float64'>
```

The problem of picking values at `0`, `1`, and `2` becomes just an array-slice. (This array-slice is an *O(n)* algorithm for array length *n*, unlike `np.searchsorted`, which would be *O(n log n)*. That's the cost of having sparse lookup keys.)

The problem, however, is that `myArray` is nested and `lookup` is not. We can give `lookup` the same depth as `myArray` by slicing it up:

```py
>>> multilookup = lookup[np.newaxis][np.zeros(len(myArray), np.int64)]
>>> multilookup
<Array [[19.5, 34.1, 10.9, ... 34.1, 10.9]] type='2 * 3 * float64'>
>>> multilookup.tolist()
[[19.5, 34.1, 10.9], [19.5, 34.1, 10.9]]
```

And then `multilookup[myArray]` is exactly what you want:

```py
>>> multilookup[myArray]
<Array [[19.5, 34.1], [10.9, 34.1, 19.5]] type='2 * var * float64'>
```

The lookup had to be duplicated because each list within `myArray` uses global indexes in the whole `lookup`. If the memory involved in creating `multilookup` is prohibitive, you could instead break `myArray` down to match it:

```py
>>> flattened, num = ak.flatten(myArray), ak.num(myArray)
>>> flattened
<Array [0, 1, 2, 1, 0] type='5 * int64'>
>>> num
<Array [2, 3] type='2 * int64'>
>>> lookup[flattened]
<Array [19.5, 34.1, 10.9, 34.1, 19.5] type='5 * float64'>
>>> ak.unflatten(lookup[flattened], nums)
<Array [[19.5, 34.1], [10.9, 34.1, 19.5]] type='2 * var * float64'>
```

If your keys are not dense from `0` up to some integer, then you'll have to use `np.searchsorted`:

```py
>>> keys = ak.Array(myDict.keys())
>>> values = ak.Array([myDict[key] for key in keys])
>>> keys
<Array [0, 1, 2] type='3 * int64'>
>>> values
<Array [19.5, 34.1, 10.9] type='3 * float64'>
```

In this case, the `keys` are trivial because it *is* dense. When using `np.searchsorted`, you have to explicitly cast the flat Awkward Arrays as NumPy (for now; we're looking to fix that).

```py
>>> lookup_index = np.searchsorted(np.asarray(keys), np.asarray(flattened), side="left")
>>> lookup_index
array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0])
```

Then we pass it through the trivial `keys` (which doesn't change it, in this case) before passing it to the `values`.

```py
>>> keys[lookup_index]
<Array [0, 1, 2, 1, 0] type='5 * int64'>
>>> values[keys[lookup_index]]
<Array [19.5, 34.1, 10.9, 34.1, 19.5] type='5 * float64'>
>>> ak.unflatten(values[keys[lookup_index]], num)
<Array [[19.5, 34.1], [10.9, 34.1, 19.5]] type='2 * var * float64'>
```

But the thing I was waffling about in yesterday's comment was that you have to do this on the flattened form of `myArray` (`flattened`) and reintroduce the structure later [ak.unflatten](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.unflatten.html), as above. But perhaps we should wrap `np.searchsorted` as `ak.searchsorted` to recognize a fully structured Awkward Array in the *second* argument, at least. (It has to be unstructured to be in the first argument.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The case where the integer keys are not dense is useful for me as well, and I believe that `values[lookup_index]` is what is needed for this case, since `keys[lookup_index]` will not index the `values` array properly since the keys are arbitrary.